# How to only get audio from MesiboGroupCall Participant - mesibo, Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, mesibo

I am building a Swift IOS-App where you should be able to do basic audio-only conferencing via mesibo. Thus why I only want the audio from the MesiboGroupCall Participant. But I don't know if there's a way to do that? And if not, what way I could use to go around that problem. By the way, I'm using a completely custom UI.

In the MesiboGroupCallInprogressListener, there's this function:

```
 func mesiboGroupcall_(onAudio p: MesiboParticipant) {
    print("[DEBUG] audio received")
 }
```

But I haven't found a way to get the audio. For the video there's also only a way to project it to their MesiboVideoView and no way to just extract the stream.